# PHP-MYSQL connection not working

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, pdo

I have just started working with php-mysql besides my daily job and since few days I am banging my head resolving the connection problem between Apache, PHP and MySQL.

Firstly I deinstalled all the PHP and mysql things that comes with Linux distro and then installed mysql 5.6.22 and php 5.6.4 on my rhel6 machine and configured php

from source using below command.

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs --with-mysql
```

After this I wrote a some code to check connection between mysql and php. Here it goes:

```
    <?php
    $host_name = "localhost";
    $database = "rating"; // Change your database name
    $username = "rate"; // Your database user id
    $password = "rate"; // Your password

    //////// Do not Edit below /////////
    try {
    $dbo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host_name.';dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     echo "Connected successfully";
    }
    catch 

(PDOException $e) {
print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
die();
}
?>
```

This throws me an error driver not found. After googling i came to know there could be missing PDO drivers and have to install that. Please help me to resolve this.

How toget my php-mysql connection working. Please help. Is my configuration command above incorrect. Please guide me and what all changes need to be done in php.ini

file.

Answer (score 0):

Use below line.

```
$dbo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host_name.';dbname='.$database.'', $username, $password);
```

Comment: @adarsh....tried this and reconfigured using below command as per instructions

./configure --with-pdo-mysql --with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock

Please tell me fom where to configure this command. from a particular directory or from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install PDO driver for your database engine (MySQL).
If you are on a debian-like distribution, you can do that:

`# apt-get install php5-mysql`

On redhat-like:

`# yum install php-mysql`

Then you need to activate it in your php.ini:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=mysql.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Then reboot apache.

Comment: [root@xxx html]# apt-get install php5-mysql
-bash: apt-get: command not found

I am on rhel6 and installed php and mysql manually instead of using default ones

Comment: @NavinGupta use yum ;) the package name is php-mysql

Comment: @DirtyVader...already tried this. gets below error.

file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.47-4.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.6.22-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/armscii8.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.47-4.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.6.22-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ascii.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.47-4.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.6.22-1.el6.x86_64 
.
.
.

Comment: Found it... You need to build PHP with: `--with-pdo-mysql`

Comment: @DirtyVader......tried this and reconfigured using below command as per instructions on http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php 

./configure --with-pdo-mysql --with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock Please tell me fom where to configure this command. from a particular directory or from anywhere.

Comment: You need to add `extension=pdo.so` too. So :
    
    extension=mysql.so
    extension=pdo.so
    extension=pdo_mysql.so

Comment: ./configure need to be executed in your PHP source folder

Comment: have added this already and I think its extension=msql.so and not extension=mysql.so. Do  i need to change extension_dir in php.ini. I haven't changed that. It's as it is 

; extension_dir = "./". Do i need to chane this. If yes what shoud be it's location

Comment: If you use MySQL, it's `extension=mysql.so` (and pdo.so and pdo_mysql.so).
If you don't know wher is your extension dir, try to search for mysql.so file, and edit your extension_dir accordingly.

Comment: There is no mysql.so file but mysql.h file is der.

Comment: and others thank you for all your support. After making some changes and reconfiguring php now m not getting driver not found error but also the script after running is not showing any success or failure message. Below is the configure command and php script i ran

./configure --with-pdo-mysql --with-mysql-sock=/ircdb/data/mysql.sock --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs --with-mysql=/
make
make install

==================
PHP Code in the next comment

Comment: <?php
$host_name = "localhost";
$database = "rating"; // Change your database name
$username = "rate"; // Your database user id
$password = "rate"; // Your password
try {
//////$dbo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host_name.';dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
$dbo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host_name.';dbname='.$database.'', $username, $password);
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 echo "Connected successfully";
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
die();
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

check your php.ini file and search   `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` if it's in comment please  uncomment this line

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```